# How do I add a column of data to an already populated table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to build a recycling bin of kinds. When I delete a column from a table, I push all the data from it into a special table called **bin**. Later on I want to be able to reconstruct this column and add it to a existing table with random data and of a random size.

### Example:

I have two tables that look like this:
               **Table1**                                           **bin**

```
| columnA | columnB |    | origin  | columnC | columnD |
| ------- | ------- |    | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|   aa    |   10    |    | columnD |   NULL  |    a    |
|   bb    |   20    |    | columnD |   NULL  |    s    |
|   cc    |   30    |    | columnD |   NULL  |    d    |
                         | columnD |   NULL  |    f    |
                         | columnC |   100   |   NULL  |
                         | columnC |   200   |   NULL  |
```

Now what I want to do is to add a column like columnC or columnD from the **bin** table to **Table1** like this:

```
| columnA | columnB | columnC |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    aa   |    10   |   100   |
|    bb   |    20   |   200   |
|    cc   |    30   |   NULL  |


| columnA | columnB | columnD |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    aa   |    10   |    a    |
|    bb   |    20   |    s    |
|    cc   |    30   |    d    |
|   NULL  |   NULL  |    f    |


| columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    aa   |    10   |   100   |    a    |
|    bb   |    20   |   200   |    s    |
|    cc   |    30   |   NULL  |    d    |
|   NULL  |   NULL  |   NULL  |    f    |
```

I'm using Python and Sqlite 3.31.1 although I am open to changing the version I use, since some people have suggested, that this one doesn't allow for join operations, so don't let that be a hinderance.

I know that I can extract a column from the bin like this:

```
SELECT columnC
FROM bin
WHERE origin='columnC'
```

But I don't know, how to insert that column starting at it's first entry into another table and fill the rest with NULL entries.

Comment: Why does column b change values in the third row?

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: How would you identify that value 100 in column should come with aa in columnA

Comment: Just by the row number basically. I want to fill the column, that I get from the bin table in order into a new column in another table.

Comment: @Obnidem I'm confused by the fact your question has two down-votes and no up-votes. It seems a reasonable question to me and, apparently, many in the community agree since folks are chiming in with clarification comments and with answers. I'm going to upvote your question and I hope the answerers and others will also. Welcome to the community.

Comment: @AnneGunn Thank you so much. I must admit, that the first draft of my description was a bit unstructured and apparently some folks weren't to happy about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that requires a full outer join, which is not available in sqlite, but can be simulated with two successive left joins and a Union All.
**Full Outer Join:**

```
SELECT A.columnA, A.columnB, B.columnC
FROM
(SELECT columnA, columnB, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM table1)A
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT columnC, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM (SELECT columnC FROM bin WHERE origin='columnC'))B
ON A.rc = B.rc
```

**Two Left Joins and a Union All:**

```
SELECT A.columnA, A.columnB, B.columnC
FROM
(SELECT columnA, columnB, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM table1)A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT columnC, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM (SELECT columnC FROM bin WHERE origin='columnC'))B
ON A.rc = B.rc
UNION ALL
SELECT A.columnA, A.columnB, B.columnC
FROM
(SELECT columnC, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM (SELECT columnC FROM bin WHERE origin='columnC'))B
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT columnA, columnB, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
AS rc FROM table1)A
ON A.rc = B.rc
WHERE A.rc IS NULL;
```

[See Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a2f8d29c0288cbe68f326721eccdffb6).

Answer (score 0):

One way to identify from which row of `bin` you will pick the value of `columnC` to update each row of `table1` is with 2 correlated subqueries which count the number of rows in each table with `rowid` less than the current `rowid`:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET columnC = (
  SELECT b1.columnC
  FROM bin AS b1 
  WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bin b2 WHERE b2.rowid < b1.rowid) =
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.rowid < t1.rowid)
)
```

This solution may not be the most efficient for a large data set, but the version of SQLite that you use does not support joins, which would perform better.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c6a6f2e86371a299354b3546e29b19ac).

Comment: That comes close, but it doesn't quite work as intended. I added two more examples to further illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: @Obnidem this query answers the question as you posted it, If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.